# What's the difference between SIMD and SSE?

Tags: x86, simd

I am confused, what's the difference between SIMD and SSE, SSE2, SSE3, AVX etc?

According to my knowledge and research, SIMD is architecture which allows for a Single Instruction to operate on multiple data and SSE, AVX are instruction sets which implement a SIMD architecture.

And also is there a difference between vector sizes of each architecture like SSE has 128 bits and AVX has 256 bits? If the underlying SIMD architecture is the same (I think), then how do different ISAs have different vector sizes?

I'm not sure if this is true, can someone explain to me in detail what actually happens?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is entirely on-topic, as you seem to be referring to the concepts themselves rather than asking a programming question.

Comment: In the same way that "grey is a color", "SSE is SIMD".

Comment: SIMD is a programming paradigm in which multiple elements of data are processed by the same instruction. SSE and AVX are both extensions of the x86 instruction set, and are implementations of this SIMD concept. There is nothing in the definition of SIMD that requires 128 bits or 256 bits to be processed at a time and no more no less. Moreover, SSE and AVX can coexist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Wikipedia page (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) does a good job of explaining SIMD, and the instruction sets that implement it.

Single instruction, multiple data (SIMD), is a class of parallel computers in Flynn's taxonomy. It describes computers with multiple processing elements that perform the same operation on multiple data points simultaneously.

SIMD is the 'concept', SSE/AVX are implementations of the concept. All SIMD instruction sets are just that, a set of instructions that the CPU can execute on multiple data points. As long as the CPU supports executing the instructions, then it is feasible for multiple SIMD instruction sets to coexist, regardless of data size.

Comment: Is cpu architecture different for different processors supporting different ISAs like cpu architecture of an x86 processor supporting SSE2 is different form a x86 based cpu supporting AVX or MIC ?

Comment: It is hard to answer that in general (and kind of off topic for SO), and depends on what your definition of CPU architecture. SIMD may be just an add-on coprocessor, meaning the 'base' CPU could be identical, for example, with the ARM cortex A8, and Neon (which was optional). Consult the specific chip documentation

Answer (score 2):

[SIMD](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) = Single Instruction, Multiple Data.  It's a concept in CPU architecture.

Many ISAs have SIMD extensions, like PowerPC's AltiVec, ARM's NEON / AArch64's ASIMD, etc.

SSE is an instruction-set extension for x86.  (And baseline for x86-64, along with SSE2).

SSE1 and SSE2 provide a bunch of SIMD load/store and computation instructions (128-bit vector width) for float (SSE1), double, and 8 to 64-bit integer types (SSE2).  Instructions like `addps xmm, xmm/m128` (add Packed Single-precision) and [`pmaddwd xmm, xmm/m128` (SSE2)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddwd).

#### But SIMD isn't the only thing that came with SSE

**SSE1+SSE2 *also* provide *scalar* instructions for float/double math** in the low elements of XMM registers, making x87 [mostly obsolete](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/are-x87-long-doubles-still-relevant/2408#2408).  Instructions like `movsd`, `addsd` (add Scalar Double-precision), `ucomisd` (compare scalar-double into Integer FLAGS, like `fcomi`).  Before SSE1/2, scalar math was done in the x87 register stack, with one-operand stack instructions, frequently requiring extra `fxch` instructions when more than one FP variable or temporary was being worked on at once.  Bad for instruction-level parallelism and not a good compiler target.

**SSE also provides some NT stores like `movntps`** to bypass cache and avoid MESI RFOs (Read For Ownership) when storing large amounts of data, so such writes don't cost double (read to fill cache and then write on eviction).  See also [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy) for more about memory bandwidth and non-RFO stores.

**SSE also provides some memory-barrier instructions** like [`sfence`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sfence) (SSE1) and [`mfence`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mfence) (SSE2).  `sfence` is useful for ordering NT stores wrt. other stores.  `mfence` would have been useful as a StoreLoad barrier if it wasn't slower than a dummy `lock or  byte [esp], 0`.  `lfence` (SSE2) also  exists but isn't useful for memory ordering in x86's already strongly-ordered memory model, but is useful for blocking out-of-order exec of instructions like `rdtsc`.  (*[Does the Intel Memory Model make SFENCE and LFENCE redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705169/does-the-intel-memory-model-make-sfence-and-lfence-redundant)*)

Many ISAs would already have memory-barrier instructions as part of their basic integer ISA, so having these as part of SSE was mostly due to SSE introducing NT stores.  Most ISAs already had non-bad scalar FP math instructions so that architectural state could get extended for SIMD, unlike x86 where the x87 stack was inconvenient and small.

---

CPUs with AVX support that as well as SSE.  For mixed element sizes or for "cleanup" of leftover elements with an odd count, it can be useful to use a mix of 128-bit and 256-bit vectors.  Or 128-bit vectors just as part of summing elements within a vector down to one, usually after a loop that summed vertically.

But normally in a function that already depends on AVX, you'd use the AVX encoding of 128-bit instructions.  CPUs with AVX support both for backwards compatibility; AVX implies SSE.  AVX1 + AVX2 provide 256-bit versions of existing FP (AVX1) and integer (AVX2) instructions, as well as adding some new instructions like shuffles.

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info for SSE history from MMX and SSE1 through later extensions.

AVX-512 has many more new instructions.