# How can I experience "LFENCE or SFENCE can not pass earlier read/write"

Tags: c, x86, inline-assembly, instructions, memory-barriers

I'm doing something about function safety. I need verify some X86 CPU instructions, such as LFENCE, SFENCE and MFENCE.

Now I can experience MFENCE according to Intel SDM chapter 8.2.3.4 "loads may be reordered with earlier store to different location".

```
"xor %0, %0\n\t                 "
"movl $1, %1\n\t                "
"mfence\n\t                     "   
"movl %2, %0\n\t                "
: "=r"(r1), "=m" (X)             
: "m"(Y)                         
: "memory");
```

```
"xor %0, %0\n\t                 "
"movl $1, %1\n\t                "
"mfence\n\t                     "   
"movl %2, %0\n\t                "
: "=r"(r2), "=m" (Y)
: "m"(X)
: "memory");
```

Above code only experience MFENCE could prevent memory reordering.(by detect the different value of r1 and r2 before/after removing mfence in both processors)

So I'm wondering how can I verify LFENCE and SFENCE like above. I didn't find any logic in SDM.

Comment: Can you clarify how the code you've shown verifies the documented behavior of `mfence`? You actually need to write many tests to check every property of all of the three fence instructions for Intel and AMD processors, which is going to take a lot of effort.

Comment: @HadiBrais: this code appears to reproduce the test from https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/.  Where StoreLoad reordering on normal WB memory is visible on x86.  It's pretty clear that's all they're trying to test.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the comments. The link exactly explained Hadi's question.
@HadiBrais If you want you can clone my test code from https://github.com/ysun/acrn-unit-test.git    with branch 'memory_ordering'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related:  [Does the Intel Memory Model make SFENCE and LFENCE redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705169/does-the-intel-memory-model-make-sfence-and-lfence-redundant)

`sfence` has no real effect unless you're using NT stores<sup>1</sup>. If you NT-store data and then a pointer to that data (or a "ready" flag), a reader can see the old value for the data even if they see the new pointer / flag value. `sfence` can be used to ensure that the two stores become observable in program order.

`lfence` is useless for memory ordering unless you're doing NT loads from a WC memory region (like video RAM).  You'll have a very hard time creating a case where commenting it out creates a detectable different *in memory ordering*.

The main use for `lfence` is to serialize *execution*, not memory.  See [Understanding the impact of lfence on a loop with two long dependency chains, for increasing lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986046/understanding-the-impact-of-lfence-on-a-loop-with-two-long-dependency-chains-fo)

---

Since you asked about C not just asm, there's a related answer about when you should use `_mm_sfence()` and other *intrinsics*.  [When should I use _mm_sfence _mm_lfence and _mm_mfence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537753/when-should-i-use-mm-sfence-mm-lfence-and-mm-mfence/50780314#50780314) (usually you really only need  `asm("" ::: "memory");` unless NT stores are in flight, because blocking compile-time reordering gives you acq / rel ordering without any runtime barrier instructions.)

---

**Footnote 1:  That's true for normal WB (WriteBack)** memory cacheability settings.  In user-space under a normal OS, that's what you always have unless you did something very special.

For other memory types (MTRR or PAT settings):  NT stores on uncacheable memory have no special effect, and are still strongly ordered.  NT stores on WC, WB, or WT memory (or normal stores to WC memory) are weakly ordered and make it useful to use  `sfence` before storing a `buffer_ready` flag for another thread.

SSE4.1 `movntdqa` *loads* from WB memory are *not* weakly ordered.  Unlike stores, it doesn't override the memory type's ordering semantics.  On current CPUs, nothing special happens at all on WB memory; they're just a less-efficient `movdqa` laod.  Only use them on WC memory.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer. I have some questions here.
For SFENCE I created a test case trying to produce memory re-ordering 
[example code for SFENCE](https://github.com/ysun/acrn-unit-test/blob/memory_ordering_SFENCE/guest/x86/memory_order.c)

Comment: @PeterCorders  As code shown.
a. I created a array by instruction MOVNTI.
b. And right after all MOVNTI, test value array[MAX] in another CPU core (a AP).
c. As my understanding according to your answer, above MOVNTI might cause memory re-ordering. In other words, the value of array[MAX] might NOT flush to memory before read in step b.
But it doesn't work as expected. Could you please correct me if my wrong understanding somewhere.

Comment: @YiSun: Yes, storing to an array with `movnti` and then writing a "buffer ready" flag with a normal store creates the *possibility* of another core seeing the flag store but stale data from the array.  I'd suggest making the array *not* a multiple of the cache-line size or not aligned, so the last store doesn't complete a 64-byte chunk and trigger immediate flush.  Especially if you have the writer go into a `pause` loop right after writing instead of doing more memory access, that might give the best chance of not flushing the WC buffer quickly.

Comment: would like illustrate more about the 'buffer ready' flag? How can I do that. I failed to search that. Great thanks !

Comment: @YiSun: That's a description, not a name you can google.  Like `std::atomic<bool> ready_flag = false;` and write it with `ready_flag.store(true, std::memory_order_release)` after doing some NT stores.

Comment: (`mo_release` *doesn't* use SFENCE, because std::atomic assumes there aren't any NT stores going on.  `mo_release` is how you get a regular store that's ordered at compile time, without the compiler inserting `mfence` or `xchg`)